# Add icons to message on console.log javascript

Tags: javascript, console, icons, console.log

This could be a sally question. But I didn't find out a property answer.

How can I add icons like this in console messages:

[image: Note hands icons]

or [image: Note hand icon]

(It could be anything else). I'm try to reach out maybe an extension for vs code, and probably exists but I don't know how to search and how could i implement on my projects.

Could you guys guide me on this please? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you unable to copy/paste?

Comment: You're showing (a picture of) a line of code which attempts to do this.  Is that not working as expected?  Are you just asking where to find emojis?  Something else?

Comment: Those are just emojis, special Unicode characters. As long as your browser and IDE are able to display them correctly, treat them the same way as any other character – just another character in a regular JS string

Comment: Thanks @mykaf. Yeah, I'm able to copy/paste. But I sow some videos where the programmer enter the image and that's it. I don't know if the appropriate way to do this is go to a icon page and copy and then return to the code and then paste

Comment: "*where the programmer enter the image and that's it.*" How did they enter the image? On Windows, [windows] + [.] opens an emoji menu.

Comment: @David it more than @ Robin270 says on his comment. That's what I need. How could achive that??? Is there a plugin or extension. And if so, whats the extension? Thank you all guys

Comment: Thank you @mykaf That's what I need. Thanks a lot man. I'm going to study the emoji menu. Thanks a lot :D